# Defined route throwing controller method not found laravel 4

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have a route defined in routes.php file but when i make an ajax request from my angular app, i get this error

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException","message":"Controller method not found.","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tedxph\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controllers\\Controller.php","line":290}}
```

this is my routes file

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Api Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
    //Auth Routes
    Route::post('auth/login', 'ApiUserController@authUser');
    Route::post('auth/signup', 'ApiUserController@registerUser');
    /* Persons */
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'people'), function() {

        Route::get('{id}', 'ApiPeopleController@read');
        Route::get('/', 'ApiPeopleController@read');
    });
    /* Events */
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'events'), function() {

        Route::get('{id}', 'ApiEventsController@read');
        Route::get('/','ApiEventsController@read');
    });
});
```

[image: chrome web inspector]
[image: Same post request in a rest client app on chrome]
Accessing the same url `(http://localhost/site/public/api/auth/signup)` from a rest client app on chrome does not give any errors, what could be wrong?

this is the angular code from my controller

```
$rootScope.show('Please wait..registering');
                API.register({email: email, password: password})
                .success(function (data) {
                    if(data.status == "success") {
                        console.log(data);
                        $rootScope.hide();
                    }
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                    $rootScope.hide();
                })
```

more angular code

```
angular.module('tedxph.API', [])
    .factory('API', function ($rootScope,  $http, $ionicLoading, $window) {
    //base url
    var base = "http://localhost/tedxph/public/api";

    return {
        auth: function (form) {
            return $http.post(base+"/auth/login", form);
        },

        register: function (form) {
            return $http.post(base+"/auth/signup", form);
        },

        fetchPeople: function () {
            return $http.get(base+"/people");
        },

        fetchEvents: function() {
            return $http.get(base+"/events");
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to POST or GET? Because you have it setup as a POST request.

Comment: its a post request am using $http.post in the API.register() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem, turns my controller was calling an undefined method in the controller class.
Renamed the method correctly and the request now works, thanks guys for the input.

Answer (score 3):

It'd help to see the code you're using to make the angular request, as well as the header information from Chrome's `Network -> XHR` logger, but my first guess would be Angular is sending the AJAX request with the `GET` method instead of the `POST` method.  Try changing Angular to send an explicit `POST` or change `routes.php` so `auth/signup` responds to both `GET` and `POST` requests.

**Update** looking at your screen shots, the AJAX request is returning an error 500.  There should be information logged to either your laravel.log file or your PHP/webserver error log as to why the error is happening.  My guess if your Angular request sends different information that your Chrome/REST-app does, and that triggers a code path where there's an error.